# Dynamically remove input field values upon clicking remove button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a file called add_field.php and scripts.js . I dynamically added the input field upon clicking add more button and data is saved into database. But I am unable to remove input field values from the wordpress database. So somebody please help me to solve this issue. I took a long time to fix this, but unable to fix it. So please help me.

[my custom admin menu page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1e7h.png)

[ajax error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwe2Z.png)

Here I am attaching the code:

**add_field.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_FieldData', 'add_FieldData'); // Logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_FieldData', 'add_FieldData'); // Guest users

add_action('wp_ajax_deleteData', 'deleteData'); // Logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_deleteData', 'deleteData'); // Guest users

function add_FieldTable() {
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    global $wpdb;
    $db_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'extra_field';
    if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$db_table_name'") != $db_table_name) {

        //sql table creation upon activating plugin
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $db_table_name . " ( 
                       `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
               `coupon` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
               `discount` int(50) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
}

function ajaxResponse($status, $message) {
    print json_encode(array (
       "status" =>  $status,
       "message" => $message
    ));
    exit;
}

function add_FieldData() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors = true;

    //checking whether the coupon and discount has value or not
    $coupon   = isset($_POST['coupon'])   ? $_POST['coupon']   : array();
    $discount = isset($_POST['discount']) ? $_POST['discount'] : array();
    //print_r($coupon); exit;
    # We excepect coupon and doscount to be array.
    # if they are not array then throw exception.
    if (!is_array($coupon) || !is_array($discount)) {
        ajaxResponse('error', 'Invalid data.');
    }

    # Item count can not be empty
    $itemCount = count($coupon);
    if (!$itemCount) {
        ajaxResponse('error', 'Empty data.');
    }
    $dbTableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'extra_field';
    $wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');

    try {
        # For each item
        for ($i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
            $couponName  = isset($coupon[$i])   ? trim($coupon[$i])   : "";
            $discountVal = isset($discount[$i]) ? trim($discount[$i]) : 0;

            # If coupon name is empty then 
            # throw error
            if(!$couponName) {
                $wpdb->query('ROLLBACK');
                ajaxResponse('error', 'Coupon name can not be empty.');
            }

            # Discount value should be numeric (both integer + float)
            # if it violates, throw error
            if (!is_numeric($discountVal)) {
                $wpdb->query('ROLLBACK');
                ajaxResponse('error', 'Discount value should be numeric.');
            }

            //For retreiving one row from the database
            $check = $wpdb->get_row(

                //Preventing from sql injection attacks
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT coupon 
                       FROM $dbTableName 
                      WHERE coupon = %s", array($couponName)
                )
            );

            if (!$check) {
                $a = $wpdb->insert($dbTableName, array(
                    'coupon' => $couponName,
                    'discount' => $discountVal
                ));

            } else { 
                $a = $wpdb->update($dbTableName, 
                    array('discount' => $discountVal), 
                    array('coupon' => $couponName)
                );
            } 
        }
        $wpdb->query('COMMIT');
        ajaxResponse('success', 'Coupon name and their respective discounts saved successfully..'); 
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $wpdb->query('ROLLBACK');
        if (WP_DEBUG) {
            ajaxResponse('error', $ex->getMessage());
        }
        ajaxResponse('error', 'Something went wrong.');
    }
}

function deleteData() {
     global $wpdb;
    $a = $wpdb->delete($dbTableName, array(
                    'coupon' => id
                ));
}
function custom_inputForm() {

    echo '
          <br>
          <strong>Welcome. Please Enter Coupon Name  & Discount[in %]</strong>
           <form action ="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method = "post">
          <div class="input_fields_wrap">
          <button class="add_field_button">Add More</button><br>
          <label for="coupon">Coupon Name:</label>
          <input id ="coupon" type="text" name="coupon[]" value = "">

          <label for="discount">Discount in %:</label>
          <input id ="discount" type="text" name="discount[]" value = "">
          </div>
          <br>
          <input id="submit" type= "submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>';
}
?>
```

**scripts.js**

```
/**
 * Javascript for collecting Admin Input Data
 * Created On: Aug 17, 2016
 * Author : BDT
 */

(jQuery)(document).ready(function () {

    //Admin clicks on submit button
    jQuery("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var couponNumber = new Array();
        jQuery("input[name='coupon[]']").each(function() {
            couponNumber.push(jQuery(this).val());
        });

        var discountItem = new Array();
        jQuery("input[name='discount[]']").each(function(){
            discountItem.push(jQuery(this).val());
        });

        //Passing the values to the corresponding function for fetching 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "add_FieldData",
                coupon: couponNumber,
                discount: discountItem
            },            
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
    var max_fields = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = (jQuery)(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = (jQuery)(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var fieldHTML = '<div><label for="coupon">Coupon Name:</label><input type= "text" name = "coupon[]" value=""/><label for="discount">Discount in %:</label><input type="text" name="discount[]" value =""/><button class="remove_field">Remove</button></div>';

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    (jQuery)(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            (jQuery)(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });

    (jQuery)(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove link
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = document.getElementById('coupon').value;
        alert(id);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
              action: 'deleteData',
              coupon: id
            },success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
        (jQuery)(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: You could make your life easier by just disabling the entries when 'Remove' is clicked. On submit, disabled entries will not be sent to the server. On the server check the data that is send, clean the entries already in database and replace them with the submitted values.  I may be missing valuable information to understand your scenario but do you really want guest users to be able to set discounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to declare the database table name in your delete function , and also you need to get the id from the ajax post.

```
function deleteData() {
        global $wpdb;
        //declare db table 
        $dbTableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'extra_field';
        //Get coupon id  from ajax post 
        if (isset($_POST['coupon'])){
            $id = $_POST['coupon'];
        }else{
            $id = "";
         }

        $a = $wpdb->delete($dbTableName, array(
                        'coupon' => $id //use the coupon id you get from ajax post 
                    ));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou I declared the datatbase table name.  still I am unable to delete the data from the database. I konw that there is some problem in passing the data.All I want is when click on particular remove button, the corresponding coupon name must be deleted. Please correct me If I am wrong :jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
              action: 'deleteData',
              coupon: id
            },success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data.message);
            }

Comment: Now I am getting value of one field . I dont kow how to loop through the query. I need to remove that particular row,when remove button is clicked.

Comment: Check the answer above , i made some changes .